# Error using v-mask in custom vuetify component

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

V-mask does not work in a vuetify v-text-field component. Apparently it generates some conflict with v-model

By applying in form this. $Refs.form.resetValidation ()
and this. $refs.form.reset () v-model variable is not reset

```
<template>
    <v-text-field
        v-model="value" 
        v-mask="mask"/>  
</template>

<script>
    import createNumberMask from 'text-mask-addons/dist/createNumberMask';

    const number = createNumberMask({
        prefix: '',
        includeThousandsSeparator: true,
        thousandsSeparatorSymbol: '.',
    });

    data: () => ({
           mask = "number"
        }),

</script>
```

The problem is that the mask is not applied.